# add a space between each word in the string

Tags: python

I've been trying to make this more challenging for myself but I couldn't find a way to achieve this goal. So I wonder if its possible to separate words that have no space  `betweenThemLikeThisJustInASingleString`
Here's my code:

```
def translate_morse(string):
    morse_a = {
    'a':'.-','b':'-...','c':'-.-.','d':'-..','e':'.','f':'..-.','g':'--.','h':'....','i':'..','j':'.---','k':'-.-','l':'.-..',
    'm':'--','n':'-.','o':'---','p':'.--.','q':'--.-','r':'.-.','s':'...','t':'-','u':'..-','v':'...-','w':'.--','x':'-..-',
    'y':'-.--','z':'--..',1:'.----',2:'..---',3:'...--',4:'....-',5:'.....',6:'-....',7:'--...',8:'---..',9:'----.',0:'-----'}
    translated = ""
    for i in string.split(' '):
        for key, value in morse_a.iteritems():
            if i == value:
                translated += key
    print translated

print """

    ###################################
    #                                 #
    #   Morse Alphabet Translator     #
    #   Author: Blackwolf             #
    #   Date: 2016-29-05              #
    #                                 #
    ###################################
    #                                 #
    #             USAGE:              #
    #  After each morse letter you    #
    #  will need to seperate (space)  #
    #  each letter                    #
    ###################################

"""
finished = False
while finished != True:
    translate_morse(raw_input("Enter morse: "))
    ask_ifFinished = raw_input('Are you done? (Y/N): ').lower()
    if ask_ifFinished == 'y':
        finished = True
```

Comment: Use the dictionary properly! Swap around the keys and values and then just do a normal dictionary lookup instead of a loop. Also those numbers need to be strings if you want to append them to a string.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to insert a space before every capital letter:

```
import re
string = 'betweenThemLikeThisJustInASingleString'
print(re.sub('([A-Z])', r' \1', string))
```

Output:

```
between Them Like This Just In A Single String
```

There's no perfect solution for splitting up words where the boundary isn't marked. How can the computer tell that `singlestring` should be split into `single string` and not `sing lest ring` (`lest` is an English word if you're not aware)? There are heuristics you could apply to make decent guesses but they're complicated and limited. You could also list all the possible solutions but that will also be difficult at your level.

Comment: what if its all in lowercase ?

Comment: That's how I'd do it. Considering his morse alphabet though, you might replace the capitals by their `lower` case variant. Also, an initial space isn't too nice ;-)

Comment: You could check for membership in a list of words of whatever language you're using (http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt) But it would be imperfect and ambiguous.

Comment: @IdontReallywolf In that case, you have a real problem: Even if you have a lexicon to look up words, word boundaries will still be ambiguous!

Comment: I think i will keep this goal for later when im more skilled :D

Answer (score 4):

First post on stackoverflow :)

Was looking at how to solve this problem for something else and figured I'd share it.

**REQUIREMENTS**

- Put spaces before each capital letter in a string.
- Here's an implementation without using 're'

```py
    def spacer(str):

    sentence = []                 # create empty list

    sentence.append(str[0])       # put first letter in list. First letter doesn't need a space.
    for char in str[1::]:         # begin iteration after first letter
        if char.islower():
            sentence.append(char) # if character is lower add to list
        elif char.isupper():
            sentence.append( " ") # if character is upper add a space to list
            sentence.append(char) # then add the upper case character to list  
    result = ''.join(sentence)    # use () join to convert the list to a string
    return result                 # return end result
```

**RUN IT**

```
string='betweenThemLikeThisJustInASingleString'
spacer(string)
```

**OUTPUT**

'between Them Like This Just In A Single String'